# Is browser Authorization Code Flow the only way to implement sso in Key Cloak

Tags: openid-connect, keycloak

I have a question regarding sso overall.

Is sso meant to be implemented only by browser auth flow which redirects users to the idp login page.

Or other ways which underneath protocols like OpenID connect provides

For example is it possible in Client Credentials Grant for REST clients like web services.

Would like to get an idea before moving forward on the implementation

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_oidc-auth-flows

> 7.1.1. OIDC Auth Flows
>   OIDC has different ways for a client or application:
>
> - Authorization Code Flow (that's probably your "browser auth flow")
> - Implicit Flow
> - Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant (Direct Access Grants)
> - Client Credentials Grant

=> yes, Keycloak supports both mentioned flows + more OpenID Connect flows as well